# LINQ Statement that parses multiple collection and gets a single List

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know if there is a better/faster way to write the following LINQ Statement.

First let me show you my class definition:

```
public class FooA
{
    public List<FooB> ListFooB { get; set; }
}

public class FooB
{
    public List<FooC> ListFooC { get; set; }
}

public class FooC
{
    public List<FooD> ListFooD { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a class that stores a list of FooA, and I need to work with the FooDs inside the FooC definition, so my LINQ looks like the following:

```
public class MagicFoo
{
    public List<FooA> ListFooA { get; set; }

    public void DoSomeMagicWithFooD()
    {
        var fooDs = from a in ListFooA
                    from b in a.ListFooB
                    from c in b.ListFooC
                    from d in c.ListFooD
                    select d;

        foreach (var fooD in fooDs)
        {
            //Do your magic with fooD...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better/faster way to write the LINQ?

Comment: You need a tree instead of lists if you want to get to the leafs faster

Comment: @Hogan Do you have an example for such an implementation?

Comment: Examples should be very easy to find.  Just think of an n-ary tree where the root node points to the elements in a.  Then look for an implementation where all the leaf nodes are stored in a list.  (This is a common optimization on trees since you often want to do it.)

Comment: XML is a good example of this too -- and XPath should let you search for terminal nodes.  That might be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in terms of *efficiency* that's creating a lot of extra objects for the sake of transparent identifiers in the translation from query expressions to `SelectMany` calls. You could convert it to:

```
var fooDs = ListFooA.SelectMany(a => a.ListFooB
                        .SelectMany(b => b.ListFooC
                           .SelectMany(c =>  c.ListFooD)));
```

That's more efficient, but less readable.

Comment: Aren't you missing the select of D?  `.Select(d => d)`

Comment: @Hogan: Nope. That's a no-op, effectively, because I'm selecting `c.ListFooD` which implements `IEnumerable<FooD>`. Both queries resolve to an `IEnumerable<FooD>`.

Answer (score -2):

fooDs.ToList().ForEach(c => c.foodd.ToList());